# ControlConnection warning in datastax java driver

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax-java-driver

I am using cassandra 2.0.9 and datastax java driver 2.0.5 to query.
I had set rpc_address as 0.0.0.0 in cassandra. Sometimes I am getting this warning message from the client

```
4411 [Cassandra Java Driver worker-1] WARN com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection - Found host with 0.0.0.0 as rpc_address, using listen_address (/192.168.100.175) to contact it instead. If this is incorrect you should avoid the use of 0.0.0.0 server side.
```

I cannot find why this warning occured sometimes only. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The driver uses the `rpc_address` set in the `system.peers` table to find the address to connect to. When you configure the rpc address to `0.0.0.0` thats what gets put in the system table so the driver cant know for sure what IP to connect to.

If possible you should just set it to its actual IP `192.168.100.175`, but if thats incorrect you may just want to add the actual address of more of your nodes to the host list the driver initially is provided.